# Two-state Markov process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stochastic-calculus

I have a Markov chain with two states $S= \{0,1\}$ where the transition rate $\mu,\nu>0$. The transition rate from 1 to 0 is $\nu$ and from 0 to 1 $\mu$. Initially $X_0 =0$. I want to:

1. Write down the transition rate matrix $W$ of the Markov chain.
2. Write down the master equation for the single-time probability  distribution $p_t(n)$ for $t\geq 0$ and $n \in S$.

**My Idea:**    The transition rate matrix is given by 
    \begin{align*}
  W = \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & \mu \\
  \nu & 0 
  \end{pmatrix}
 \end{align*}
    The eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1,2} = \mp \sqrt{\mu \nu}$, which gives the eigenvectors \begin{align*}
\mathbf{v}_{1}=\left[\begin{array}{c}{-\sqrt{\mu / \nu}} \\ {1}\end{array}\right], \quad \mathbf{v}_{2}=\left[\begin{array}{c}{\sqrt{\mu / \nu}} \\ {1}\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
    The matrixexponential is then 
    \begin{align*}
  p_t(n) &= V \exp(D t) V^{-1} \\
  &= \begin{bmatrix}
   \sqrt{\mu/\nu} &  -\sqrt{\mu / \nu} \\
  1 & 1 
  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
  \exp(-\sqrt{\mu / \nu} t) & 0 \\
  0 & \exp(\sqrt{\mu / \nu } t) 
  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
   -\frac{\sqrt{\nu }}{2 \sqrt{\mu }} & \frac{1}{2} \\
  \frac{\sqrt{\nu }}{2 \sqrt{\mu }} & \frac{1}{2} \\
  \end{bmatrix} \\
  &= \mathrm{e}^{-t \sqrt{\mu \nu}} \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} \left(1+e^{2 t \sqrt{\mu  \nu }}\right) & \frac{\left(-1+e^{2 t \sqrt{\mu 
   \nu }}\right) \sqrt{\mu }}{2 \sqrt{\nu }} \\
\frac{\left(-1+e^{2 t \sqrt{\mu  \nu }}\right) \sqrt{\nu }}{2 \sqrt{\mu }} & \frac{1}{2}
\left(1+e^{2 t \sqrt{\mu  \nu }}\right) \\
  \end{bmatrix}
 \end{align*}
Now I need the master equation, but I'm not sure how to get it. Furthermore I'm not sure if my solution is correct so far or if there is an easier way.

Comment: This is a continuous time MC? Then the rows of the generator $Q$-matrix should sum to $0$ and the diagonals should be negative (non-positive). What you have written for $W$ is neither the $Q$-matrix, the associated jump-matrix, nor the semigroup $P(t)=e^{tQ}$ (in the case of finite state space).

Comment: Yes I consider a continous time MC. My idea was to take the transition matrix (where the columns should sum up to 1, which I done wrong) and then I put it into the equation you mentioned $P=\exp(t W)$. But maybe my attempt using the transition rate matrix as the jump rate matrix $Q$ you mentioned is wrong. Hence, from my perspective I should have started with \begin{align*}
  W = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 - \mu & \mu \\
  \nu & 1 - \nu 
  \end{pmatrix}
 \end{align*}

Comment: I think you might be confusing some concepts. For *discrete time* Markov chains, one uses the probability transition matrix written in the form in your previous comment—where rows sum to $1$ and each entry is a *probability*. For continuous time MCs the $Q$-matrix or (also called generator or the transition rate matrix) is the main focus. Here the entries are *rates* and the rows *sum  to zero*. Then the semigroup is obtained via $P=e^{t Q}$ and these entries are probabilities. To be explicit, \begin{align*} Q=\begin{pmatrix} -\mu & \mu \\ \nu & -\nu \end{pmatrix} \end{align*} is...(continued)

Comment: (Continued) the general form of the $Q$ matrix for a two state CTMC. From here you can either compute $Q^n$ for each $n$ (by induction) and then plug that into the Taylor series for $e^{tQ}$ or use the eigen-decomp to find $P(t)$.

Comment: Any luck? If you’re still having trouble let me know what you tried and I can write up an answer with more details.

Comment: After calculating $P=V\mathrm{e}^{tQ}V^{-1}$ I'm left with $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{e^{-t \mu -t \nu } \mu }{\left(\frac{\mu }{\nu }+1\right) \nu }+\frac{1}{\frac{\mu
   }{\nu }+1} & \frac{\mu }{\left(\frac{\mu }{\nu }+1\right) \nu }-\frac{e^{-t \mu -t \nu
   } \mu }{\left(\frac{\mu }{\nu }+1\right) \nu } \\
 \frac{1}{\frac{\mu }{\nu }+1}-\frac{e^{-t \mu -t \nu }}{\frac{\mu }{\nu }+1} & \frac{\mu
   }{\left(\frac{\mu }{\nu }+1\right) \nu }+\frac{e^{-t \mu -t \nu }}{\frac{\mu }{\nu
   }+1} \\
\end{array}
\right)$ The entries of that matrix can be used for the master equation...

Comment: For example $P_{s,t}(0,0)$ is the first entry and so on. The master equation should now be something like $\dot{P}_{s,t}(x,y) = \sum_z \left(Q_t(z,y) P_{s,t}(x,z) - Q_t(y,z) P_{s,t}(x,y) \right] $, but do I have now for every entry one differential equation? Like $\dot{P}_{s,t}(0,0) = ...$ and how do I write it down?

Comment: When I calculate the eigenvalues of $Q$, one of the two equals $0$. Can this matrix still have eigenvectors?